# Pro Tools 9, Should I go for it?

Tags: pro-tools, upgrade, money

Hello

I'm a student at the moment so moneys a bit tight. I'm currently running Pro tools 7.4 with a M-Box.

I was wondering what peoples experience with Pro tools 9 is and whether it's worth spending the cash and upgrading.

I'm mostly using it for mixing and editing sounds rather then creating new sounds.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

not only do you get more tracks with PTLE8 and PT9, you do also get a nice collection of plugins that didn't exist in 7.4. also if tomorrow your situation changes and you're asked to import someone's video to work to, PT9 has something PT8 and 7.4 didn't have.. also a more polished interface will have you feeling in a different way. to some people it tends to be important..

Comment: Personally, 7.4 does the job just fine for me. I think if someone was put off by what version of Pro Tools you are running as opposed to your skill in using it, it's their loss. At that point, it's like a woman not dating a man because of what year car he drives (woops, wrong analogy, there are tons of those around...)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you are a student and money is tight.  PT 7.4 is more than enough to edit, mix, and become proficient with the software.  Save your money, PT9 will not be a huge leap for you.  We don't always need the latest and greatest to do our work, when money is an issue, it is best to get by with what you have.

Comment: To add, I do use PT9.  I upgraded only because I wanted the Eucon support for my Euphonix controllers.  I also make money using my system, so the cost of upgrading isn't an issue.

Comment: @Chuck I run 7.4 and have a EuCon 8-fader controller, and it still doesn't recognize VCAs. With Pro Tools 9 does it recognize them?

Comment: @Utopia I never tried it with 7.4 but even with 8.1 under HUI I could control VCA faders with my MC Control